# Storing a hovered element in a state service subject does not emit any data on subscribe - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, rxjs, hover

I have a project consisting of a calendar, a hover directive and a stateful service for communication. I did a much more simpler representation of what I work with here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kvzyvy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

The calendar needs to store the clicked date and the most recently hovered date too. The first works, the second - not at all. Hover directive and `nexting()` seem to be working, but neither `async` pipe nor ordinary `subscribe` won't get any value out.

Might it be a trivial thing or something I'm overlooking here? I guess it puzzles me for longer than it should..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured that out on my own - the reason is plain stupid.

I was not aware I have been actually creating several instances of `state service`, because I set `provider` field in `appHover` directive and did not set `providedIn: 'root'` in `stateful.service.ts`. The first one provided a separate service for each directive use, so given five calendar 'boxes', I ended up with 5 instances of the service.

Here is example that finally works.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4owtds?file=src%2Fdate-picker%2Fdate-picker.component.ts